# Update Pandas DataFrame with extra columns?

Tags: python, pandas

In Pandas, you can update a dataframe with the data from another dataframe.

```
X = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,8],'b':[2,4,6,4]})
Y = pd.DataFrame({'b':[10,20,30,40],'c':[5,6,7,8]})
X.update(Y)
   a   b
0  1  10
1  2  20
2  3  30
3  8  40
```

Is there a way to do it so that the extra columns from Y are included? e.g.

```
X.update(Y)
   a   b  c
0  1  10  5
1  2  20  6
2  3  30  7
3  8  40  8
```

Of the other [likely candidate methods](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.2/api.html#id9), `X.join(Y)` wants to keep both 'b' columns, `X.merge(Y)` return an empty DF, `X.merge(Y, how='right')` returns 'a' column full of NANs.

Obviously I could do this by joining then deleting columns, but it gets messy and memory hungry.

Comment: I think that replacing the values in `'b'` and adding the values from `'c'` are two pretty distinct operations. You can do it in one step with `X[['b', 'c']] = Y[['b', 'c']]` (assuming you spell out the columns explicitly), but I don't think `merge` and `join` will give you a way to do the two different operations with a single call.

Comment: Hrm. Fair enough. Actually `X.join(Y[Y.columns[[c not in X for c in Y]]])` works, but I don't know if it's the best way...

Comment: Do you actually need the more complex joining behavior, or are you only doing this with DataFrames that are already aligned?

Comment: Er.. `X[X.columns[[c not in Y for c in X]]].join(Y, how='outer')`. The Dataframes are already aligned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the DataFrames already have the same index (as in your example), you can do it without any updating or joining:

```
>>> pandas.concat([X[X.columns - Y.columns], Y], axis=1)
    a   b  c
0  1  10  5
1  2  20  6
2  3  30  7
3  8  40  8
```

The idea is you want only the columns unique to X, plus all the columns from Y.  (The DataFrame `columns` attribute gives a pandas Index, and these objects support set-like operations such as difference, union, and intersection.)

Comment: Wow, that index subtraction is very cool. Is there any difference in performance between this and the equivalent from my comment on the question? `X[X.columns - Y.columns].join(Y)`

Comment: @naught101: I'm not sure, but my hunch is that anything involving a join will be slower (or at least no faster).